# Using d3 script in GWT application using JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni, d3.js

I am trying to integrate a d3 script into gwt web-app. However I cannot figure it out how to run the d3 from JSNI. The d3 code works well separately; I am wondering it may be because the d3 code cannot access the div element? 

 This is the approach I am following:
+ add the 'script' tags in the main html file head, to specify the d3 libraries
+ Put the following d3 code in a method, using JSNI, and call the method in onModuleLoad(). the d3 code accesses the main div element, which the rootPanel is also using.

```
/*-{

    var w = 960, h = 800;
    var svg = d3.select("#chart2")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(40, 0)");

        svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data([ 32, 57, 112, 293 ])
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cy", 90)
            .attr("cx", String)
            .attr("r", Math.sqrt);

}-*/;
```

I also tried another approach; I added another div element inside a HTML element in the Java class, and tried to access the second div from the d3.

In both cases nothing is showing up. any idea how it might work please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you [read the docs on JSNI](https://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)?

For starters:

1. You should [include external JS dependencies via the module](https://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion) *.gwt.xml file.
2. Properly reference the scope of the library via the **$wnd** and **this** variables.

This is not garden variety JS here, you need to follow by the rules in their JSNI docs. See [one](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html) of the [many tutorials](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html) on JSNI library wrapping out there.

Comment: amen to that. @Ehsan please refer to this [reference on overlay types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) for a quick, handful, tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the the helpful information.
I will follow the comments and update the post with the results.

Answer (score 9):

I have put together a short example of how to integrate d3 into GWT:

https://github.com/lgrammel/d3_gwt

Basically, you convert your Java objects into JavaScript objects using
JSNI and pass them into the JavaScript method
that contains the d3 code:

https://github.com/lgrammel/d3_gwt/blob/master/src/de/larsgrammel/d3_gwt/client/D3_gwt.java

https://github.com/lgrammel/d3_gwt/blob/master/war/d3_vis.js

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what was previously said you can also check out the  [GWT wrapper for Protovis](http://code.google.com/p/choosel/wiki/ProtovisGWT).
d3.js and protovis have similar design [principles](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/protovis.html) (both are developed by [Mike Bostock](https://github.com/mbostock))

So you can get a lot of ideas from the protovisGWT wrapper and maybe you can also even implement a GWT wrapper for d3.js.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.
I will follow the comments and update the post with the results.

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer...
But [this](https://github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3) project is maybe what you want:

It's a GWT wrapper around `d3.js`.